# Processing Complex Avro messages using Kafka Streams

Tags: java, apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-streams

I am working on a POC on Kafka Streams in which I am processing avro messages using Kafka Streams. Thing is that my Avro message has mix of simple and complex types, so I am finding it difficult in processing it.

My Avro Schema looks like below.

```
{"type":"record",
"namespace": "com.test",
"name": "backoffice",
"fields": [ {"name": "accountid","type": "string"},
{"name":"amendmentpositionid","type": "int"},
{"name":"booking","type":
{"type":"array","items":
{"namespace":"com.saxo",
"name":"bookingfields",
"type":"record",
"fields":
[{"name":"accountid","type":"string"},{"name":"clientid","type":"int"},
{"name":"clientname","type":"string"},{"name":"exerciseid","type":"int"},
{"name":"hedgeid","type":"int"},{"name":"originatingpositionid","type":"int"},
{"name":"positionid","type":"int"},{"name":"relatedpositionid","type":"int"} ]}}}]}
```

Input Data is mentioned as below

```
{"accountid":"1234","amendmentpositionid":1234,"booking":[{"accountid":"898","clientid":333,"clientname":"Non ","exerciseid":2,"hedgeid":100
```

I need it to flatten and look like as mentioned below before storing it to database.

```
1234,1234,898,333,NON,2,100
```

To achieve this I am trying to use Kafka Streams flatmapvalues operation but somehow I am not able to retain id and date in my final output.

My kafka Streams application looks like below.

```
package com.test.office.KafkaStreams;

import io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig;
import io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializerConfig;
import io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.GenericAvroSerde;
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.KeyValue;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsConfig;
//import io.confluent.kafka;
//import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes.
//import io.confluent.kafka.serialiszers.AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig;
import io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.SpecificAvroSerde;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStream;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStreamBuilder;
import com.saxo.backoffice;
import io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.GenericAvroSerde;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KeyValueMapper;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;

public class KafkaAvroSchemaRegistry {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "Kafka Avro Topic 8");
        properties.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "server1");
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        properties.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
        properties.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, SpecificAvroSerde.class);
        properties.put(AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, "http://server2:8081");

        KStreamBuilder builder = new KStreamBuilder();
        KStream<String, testSpecific> testspecific1 = builder.stream("topic10");

        KStream<String,testspecific> output1 = testspecific1.peek((key,value) -> System.out.println(key + value.toString()));


output1.print();
KStream<String,String> test = testspecific1.flatMapValues(value -> value.Booking());

test.print()
        KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder, properties);

        streams.cleanUp();
        streams.start();


        // print the topology
       // System.out.println(streams.toString());

        // shutdown hook to correctly close the streams application
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(streams::close));
    }
}
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> somehow I am not able to retain id and date in my final output.

Because you're only mapping out into `getMessage()`.

Try getting all the fields

```
flatMapValues(value -> 
    String.format("%d,%s,%s", value.getId(), value.getDate(), value.getMessage());
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What if I have below mentioned schema. 
"fields": [ {"name": "accountid","type": "string"},
{"name":"amendmentpositionid","type": "int"},
{"name":"booking","type":
{"type":"array","items":
{"namespace":"com.saxo",
"name":"bookingfields",
"type":"record",
"fields":
[{"name":"accountid","type":"string"},{"name":"clientid","type":"int"},
{"name":"clientname","type":"string"},{"name":"exerciseid","type":"int"},
{"name":"hedgeid","type":"int"},{"name":"originatingpositionid","type":"int"},
{"name":"relatedpositionid","type":"int"} ]}}}]}
}

Comment: What about it? If you want CSV, then you need to call each getter for every field

Comment: I tried it like this. KStream<String,String> test1 = backofficetopic1.flatMapValues(value -> String.format("%d,%s", value.getAmendmentpositionid(),value.getAccountid());
 But this is not working.

Comment: And what about that doesn't work? `value.getAccountId()` doesn't exist in that schema

Comment: Note: You are not limited to doing a single operation in `flatMapValues`, you can have a whole block there, like `flatMapValues(value -> { List<BookingField> bookingFields = value.getBooking(); return String.format(...);  })`

Comment: Tried this but throwing error.     KStream<String,String> test1 = backofficetopic1.flatMapValues(value -> {List<com.text.bookingfields> bookingfieldss = value.getBooking(); return bookingfieldss.toString();});

Comment: Sorry, but you need to be more specific

Comment: sorry for being late. Below is the issue.  I have data in below mentioned format           
   TRADEDATAS | ARRAY<STRUCT<CLIENTID INTEGER, BOOKING STRUCT<CLIENTID INTEGER, ACCOUNTID VARCHAR(STRING), POSITIONID BIGINT, CLIENTNAME VARCHAR(STRING)>>>    I want to flatten this data such that it looks like individual columns in database. Basically what i understood is that i need to iterate over this array TRADEDATAS. II am trying this in KSQL but i can only select elements using indices but not all. Can KSQL do this? If not then can u tell me how to do it in KStreams. Sorry I am new to it.

Comment: I think KSQL can only do 1:1 mappings, it cannot explode an `array<struct>` into multiple `struct`. My answer seems to already show what you need to do in Kafka Streams. You have a `Stream<Key, Collection<Record>>`, then you `flatMapValues`, and the output then becomes `Stream<Key, Record>`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried to achieve it using flatmap as mentioned below and it has worked.  KStream<String,TradeData> output = trademessage.flatMapValues(tradedata -> tradedata.getTradedatas());
List<String> output1 =  new ArrayList<>();
output.foreach((key,value)->System.out.println(String.format("%d,%s" ,value.getClientid(),value.getBooking().getAccountid())));   I wanted to check if there is any way to store the data of individual columns into Kafka Topic in JSON/Avro? I wanted to use Kafka Connect to read this output data and store it in DB. Also i have accepted your answer.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `System.out.println` unless you just wanted to **see** the data... And Kafka topics don't have "columns", only fields. But yes, you can use write out the KStream `to()` another topic, and give it a SerDe to use. Then use `JSONFormat` or `AvroFormat` within the S3 or HDFS Connectors. I don't have much experience with the other database connectors.

Comment: I can write it to another streams using .to but thing is that first flatmap operation only flatten the first array but there is one more struct inside that if you see above. I wanted to flatten that struct as well into multiple kafka fields before storing it to Kafka. Is there a way to do that? Do I need to provide another flatmapvalues? Basically My output fields should be like (clientid,bookindclientid,accuntid,positionid,clientname)

Comment: I can't tell what you're trying to do based on just a comment, sorry. Perhaps you should post a new question with your problem?